# ReferenceError: count_1 is not defined in a Joomla module

Tags: javascript, setinterval, referenceerror

This is my script:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var START_DATE_1 = new Date("July 18, 2016 10:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL_1 = 3; // in seconds
    var INCREMENT_1 = 1; // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE_1 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
    var count_1 = 0;

    var msInterval_1 = INTERVAL_1 * 1000;
    var now_1 = new Date();
    count_1 = parseInt((now_1 - START_DATE_1)/msInterval_1) * INCREMENT_1 + START_VALUE_1;
    document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;
    setInterval("count_1 += INCREMENT_1; document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;", msInterval_1);
  });
</script>
```

I've placed it inside a Joomla module. Firebug says: "ReferenceError: count_1 is not defined"

Why? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a function instead of a string to the `setInterval` call. When you pass a string, it is executed in the global scope, and `count_1` variable exists only in the scope of the callback function passed to `addEventListener`.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var START_DATE_1 = new Date("July 18, 2016 10:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL_1 = 3; // in seconds
    var INCREMENT_1 = 1; // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE_1 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
    var count_1 = 0;

    var msInterval_1 = INTERVAL_1 * 1000;
    var now_1 = new Date();
    count_1 = parseInt((now_1 - START_DATE_1)/msInterval_1) * INCREMENT_1 + START_VALUE_1;
    document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;
    setInterval(function() {
      count_1 += INCREMENT_1;
      document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;
    }, msInterval_1);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Gothdo, that worked! Would you please help me also to render the numbers of the counter with thousand separator (example 3.234.000)?

Comment: @Francesco You should ask that as a new question. Comments are not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in a string as the first argument to the timers function, they actually create a script object with that as source:

> **[Otherwise]**
>
> Perform HostEnsureCanCompileStrings(callerRealm, calleeRealm). If this throws an exception, report the exception.
>
> Let script source be the first method argument.
>
> Let settings object be method context's environment settings object.
>
> Let script be the result of creating a classic script using script source and settings object.
>
> Run the classic script script.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-setinterval

So, it's not exactly as `eval` where you actually get access to the scope of the function. The script object should have access to the global scope. The reason it fails is because is because it looks for `count_1` on the global scope through `count_1 += INCREMENT` which isn't find and therefore returns the `ReferenceError`.

Best way to avoid this type of errors is to not use a string as an argument for the timers function.